# How to play a wav audio file type in IE (11)

Tags: html

I have a problem in playing wav audio files but looks perfect when i use mp3 instead.

```
<audio prelaod src="sampleofaudio.wav" type="audio/wav">
```

Is there any plugin or any additional javascript method (instead of using embed tag) that i need to include?

Comment: IE11 does not support `.wav` files, nor is it at all *sensible* to use an uncompressed audio file on a web page.

Comment: There a really nice table that shows which browsers support which audio formats [**here**](https://caniuse.com/#search=audio%20format) :)

Comment: Yes i know that guys, im looking for a another solution or hacking trick

Comment: @RudyReus The solution is to transcode it to MP3 or some other supported format.